# How to replace only one value in array at a time

Tags: arrays, ruby, indexing, replace, iteration

I have a problem with replacing values in an array. 
I would like to replace one value in the `array1` with value from the `array2`. I know index of a value from the `array2` and I want to add its value in exact same place in the `array1`.

here's my try:

```
array_1 = ["t","t","t"]
array_2 = ["a","a","c"]
array_2_index =[0,1]
```

I want to replace `array_1[1]` to `array_2[1]`
Output should be like this:

```
array1 =["a","a","t"]

@array2_index.map { |i| array_2[i].replace array_1[i] }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
array_1 = ["t","t","t"]
array_2 = ["a","a","c"]

array1_index = 0
array2_index = 2 

array_2.delete_at(array2_index)
array_2.insert(array2_index, array1[array1_index])
```

This returns `['a', 'a', 't']`

You are deleting the element you want to replace, then insert the new element at the same index.

You can wrap all of this in a method, like so

```
def replace_element(array1, array2, array1_index, array2_index)
  array_2.delete_at(array2_index)
  array_2.insert(array2_index, array1[array1_index])
end
```

Say if you have a 2d array of index to replace,

```
index = [[0,1],[2,3],[4,5]]
```

You can loop through each and run the method

```
index.each do |array1_index, array2_index|
  replace_element(array1, array2, array1_index, array2_index)
end
```

Comment: wonderful!
I'm also struggling with iteration. 
How can I iterate through array with indexes which are common for arr1 and arr2. How can I implement this inside a method?
`array_1 = ["t","-","-"]
array_2 = ["a","a","c"]
index = [0,1]
array_1.delete_at(i)
array_1.insert(i, array_2[i])`

Comment: Since [Array#delete_at](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_at) returns the element being deleted (assuming the index is within range), you can save a step with `array_2.insert(array2_index,  array_2.delete_at(array2_index))`.

Comment: but it only works if inside index array is only one index. What should I do if I want to replace few at the time?

`def mix(index, array_1, array_2 )
arr = index.map {|i| 
array_1.delete_at(index[i])
array_1.insert(index[i], array_2[i])}
end`

Comment: jukalong, if you want to remove elements at `n` indices in `array2` and insert them at given positions in `array12` just perform the operation `n` times. It's a bit tricky, however, since you changing the sizes of both arrays. You will have to start at the end of each array and work backward for the indices to work out correctly.

Comment: Thank you guys! @davidhu2000

Comment: Am I missing something or would `array_1[1] = array2[1]` not do this without all the mess?